# How to add checkboxes to a search result in php/html

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms

I have a list of users in my database that I am able to search for users with specific things like their job categories, salaries, etc. But what I need now is to have checkboxes next to each search result so that I can add the results that are checked to show up in a different page. How do I add checkboxes to each displayed search result? I have searched all over google with no luck or maybe I just didn't understand it.

This is my php code so far:

```
 <form method="POST">
     <input type="TEXT" name="search" />
     <input type="SUBMIT" name="submit" value="Search" />

    </form>
    <form>

    <?php


    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $mysqli = NEW mysqli('localhost','root','','lr');

    $search = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['search']);

    $resultSet = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE jobcat LIKE '%$search%' ");

    if($resultSet->num_rows > 0){
    while($rows = $resultSet->fetch_assoc())
    { 
    $first_name = $rows['first_name'];
    $last_name = $rows['last_name'];
    $education = $rows['education'];
    $salary = $rows['salary'];
    $jobcat = $rows['jobcat'];

    echo "<br />First Name: $first_name<br />Last Name: 
    $last_name<br />Job Category: $jobcat<br />Education: 
    $education<br />Salary: $salary<br /><br />";
        }
     }
    else {
         echo "No Results";
     }
    }

     ?>

     </form>
```

Comment: start by removing the 2nd set of form tags. I've no idea why you have that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo "<br /><input type='checkbox' name='' value=''> 
First Name: $first_name<br />Last Name: 
$last_name<br />Job Category: $jobcat<br />Education: 
$education<br />Salary: $salary<br /><br />";
```

Comment: Weird I tried it earlier and it gave me a syntax error but it worked this time. Is there a way to limit the amount of selected checkboxes for it? Thanks!

Comment: You'll notice I'm using single quotes inside the checkbox. If you used double quotes you need to escape them, i.e. `\"` else you'll get an error. I'm not sure what you mean about limiting selected checkboxes.

Comment: Oh maybe that was my issue. As far as the selected checkboxes, I mean only being able to select up to 3 search results. So if 5 results displayed, you can check 3 out of the 5 instead of all 5.

Comment: Check my second post. Selecting 3 checkboxes will disable the other two, until you uncheck one of the checkboxes.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is with Jquery.

```js
function myFunc() {

  if ($('#myForm').find('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length == 3) {

    $('#myForm input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
      if ($(this).prop('checked') == false) {
        $(this).prop('disabled', true);
      }
    });
  } else {
    $('#myForm input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
      $(this).prop('disabled', false);
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="myForm">
  <input type="checkbox" name="myCheckbox[]" onclick="myFunc()"> Checkbox 1<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="myCheckbox[]" onclick="myFunc()"> Checkbox 2<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="myCheckbox[]" onclick="myFunc()"> Checkbox 3<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="myCheckbox[]" onclick="myFunc()"> Checkbox 4<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="myCheckbox[]" onclick="myFunc()"> Checkbox 5<br>
</form>
```